# css box-shadow not showing

Tags: javascript, css, jss

I am facing an issue with css box-shadow..
At the company we use material ui and react base table from our own story book.

My problem is that I am currently replacing react virtualized table with react base table.

I had the following box-shadow styling on the header row that was working:

```
 .ReactVirtualized__Table {
        .ReactVirtualized__Table__headerRow {
            background-color: #ffffff;
            box-shadow: 0 3px 3px -2px rgba(36, 36, 36, 0.12), 0 3px 4px 0 rgba(36, 36, 36, 0.14),
                0 1px 8px 0 rgba(36, 36, 36, 0.2);
   }
}
```

After implementing react base table I added it the following way (side note, we use jss styling):

```
 root: {
    '& .BaseTable__header': {
      boxShadow:
        '0 3px 3px -2px rgba(36, 36, 36, 0.12), 0 3px 4px 0 rgba(36, 36, 36, 0.14), 0 1px 8px 0 rgba(36, 36, 36, 0.2)',
      fontWeight: 'normal',
      position: 'relative',
    },
}
```

tried differently too:

```
 boxShadow: [
        [0, 3, 3, -2, 'rgba(36, 36, 36, 0.12)'],
        [0, 3, 4, 0, 'rgba(36, 36, 36, 0.14)'],
        [0, 1, 8, 0, 'rgba(36, 36, 36, 0.2)'],
      ],
```

The shadow appears below the header row, but not above... I cannot figure out what could be the issue.

Comment: There could be several reasons why the box-shadow appears below the header row but not above it. Here are some things you could try to troubleshoot the issue:

I don't have any context cus I've not used either of these tools before, but you can check the following 

- That the element you are applying the box-shadow to has a higher z-index than any other element that might be overlapping it.
- Make sure that the element you are applying the box shadow to has a position set to relative, absolute, or fixed.
- and make sure react base table supports additional style properties.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I don't know why it was working with react virtualized by default, but here I had to push the header row a little down with a margin top and it appeared..

Answer (score 0):

Syntax of `box-shadow` is

`box-shadow: offset-x | offset-y | blur-radius | spread-radius | color ;`

So if you want to appears `box-shadow` above:

set the `offset-x`` value with (-)(minus)

**Example:**

```
box-shadow: -2px 2px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
```